# WSO2 EntitlementPolicyAdminService using Rest API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have using WSO2 identity server,but i have facing problem for Policy creation,
because this is available in XACML Poliicy.

Document :
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Entitlement+with+APIs#EntitlementwithAPIs-publishToPDP()

any plugin any anything available for convert to REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no straight forward way to utilize PAP operations in REST way. But there are couple of alternate solutions.

1. If you are good in WSO2 EI (previously WSO2 ESB) you can use SOAP to REST transformation as per [1]
2. You can write your own java component as JAX-RS service in WSO2 Identity Server [2]

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-RESTClientandSOAPService

[2]https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/10/article-exposing-wso2-identity-server-admin-services-the-rest-way/